# link MAC adresses and port IDs

Tags: text-processing, mac-address

I have text file which include MAC address and its relevant ports, these were ordered in a way where the MAC address matches the single number of the same line numbers, in other words MAC address on line 1 matches the first single number and the second MAC address matches the second single number and so on ...

I would like to match each MAC and port 
for example the file below:

```
"1e 47 29 00 A0 60 "
"1e 47 29 00 A0 64 "
"1e 47 29 00 A0 AF "
"1e 47 29 00 B1 50 "
"0C 72 0A 27 5F 71 "
"0C 72 0A 27 BC BA "
"2B 07 D4 A2 30 CD "
"2B 07 D4 A2 33 64 "
9
3
7
1
4
2
10
8
```

I want to remove the quote "" from the MACs, add the port number beside it on the right and separate MAC and port by a colon like this

```
1e 47 29 00 A0 60 :9
1e 47 29 00 A0 64 :3
1e 47 29 00 A0 AF :7
1e 47 29 00 B1 50 :1
0C 72 0A 27 5F 71 :4
0C 72 0A 27 BC BA :2
2B 07 D4 A2 30 CD :10
2B 07 D4 A2 33 64 :8
1B 02 D7 A4 23 65 :19
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` and `sed` combination:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR/2;i++)print a[i]":"a[i+(NR/2)]}' file | sed 's/"//g'

1e 47 29 00 A0 60 :9
1e 47 29 00 A0 64 :3
1e 47 29 00 A0 AF :7
1e 47 29 00 B1 50 :1
0C 72 0A 27 5F 71 :4
0C 72 0A 27 BC BA :2
2B 07 D4 A2 30 CD :10
2B 07 D4 A2 33 64 :8
1B 02 D7 A4 23 65 :19
```

Answer (score 1):

A `awk` only solution:

```
awk 'gsub("\"",""){a[++i]=$0;next}{print a[++j]":"$0}' file
```

Comment: Implicit check of gsub ? Very clever

Comment: @Archemar `gsub` return the number of substitution performed, so the associated statement will only be executed for quoted MAC addresses.